# How to share certain variable when using rfork() in c program?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, fork, freebsd

I was wondering if is possible to share certain variable for child process when I use rfork() in freebsd?

When I use RFMEM flag, it will share all the data, that's not I want, but I didn't find the right way ...

Thanks a lot!

reference:
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rfork&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+9.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Comment: It seems there no way to only share part of the memory when forking. What you *could* do is do a `rfork` not sharing data, and then use shared memory to share data between the processes.

Comment: If is possible to lock/synchronous the shared variable between processed if I used the method you said? thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. Do a search for "posix semaphores" (as well as "posix shared memory").